# MySQL returning false when multiple rows meet WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table:

```
ID       NAME      GROUP
123456   Example   1
789012   Test      2
345678   Lorem     1
```

This code works fine:

```
select * from mytable where id="789012"
```

However, this code fails:

```
select * from mytable where group="1"
```

Why is this? Isn't the whole point of iterating with the `while` loop to return multiple rows?

Comment: Becuse you are using reserved keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query fails. You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `group` with backticks

```
select * from mytable where `group` = 1
```

Comment: I hate when a solution is something entirely irrelevant from what I thought was the error. Thank you.

Comment: A better idea is to not use reserved words