# Multiple rows from db

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to echo out multiple rows from a sql database, but I get the error Warning. Illegal string offset 'Date' In....

```
$channel_check = mysql_query("SELECT content, Date FROM wgo WHERE Posted_By='$user' ORDER by `id` DESC;");
    $numrows_cc = mysql_num_rows($channel_check);
    if ($numrows_cc == 0) {
echo ''; 

// They don't have any channels so they need to create one?><h4> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspYou haven't posted anything yet. You can post what's going on in your life, how you're feeling, or anything else that matters to you.</h4>


 <?php
}
else
{
?>
<div id="recentc">
</div>
<?php
echo"<h2 id='lp'> Latest Posts</h2>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($channel_check)) {
  $channel_name = $row['content']['Date'];
 ?>
 <div style="margin-top:60px;">
 <hr style="margin-right:340px;width:600px; opacity:0;">

            <?php echo "<div id='rpc'><h6> $channel_name</h6></div>";?>
   </div>
<?php
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Aside: to shift a title to the right, it'd be better to use CSS rather than long lists of non-breaking spaces, but if you _have_ to use the latter, `&nbsp;` requires a semi-colon at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is 1-dimensional array with 2 fields: **content** and **Date**.

Try,

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($channel_check)) {
    print_r($row);
    //$channel_name = $row['content']['Date'];
```

Comment: It works except : adsff

 Array ( [content] => adfasdf [Date] => 2013-12-22 ) that entire text comes out on my website, not just adfasdf - 2013-12-22

Comment: Fixed it: Solution ==   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($channel_check)) {
  $channel_name = $row['content'];
  $channel_name2 = $row['Posted_By'];
  $channel_name3 = $row['Date'];

Answer (score 2):

DATE is a datatype in SQL, you need to escape it with back ticks

```
SELECT content, `Date` FROM wgo WHERE Posted_By='$user' ORDER by `id` DESC
```

Also, you're accessing your row incorrectly. Rows are typically represented by a uni-dimensional array, so $row['content'] and $row['Date']

Comment: `DATE` is **NOT** a reserved word => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I consider any word you can't use without escaping or delimiting a reserved word, DATE being one of them, but that's personal opinion. However, you are correct that it's not on that list, answer edited.

Comment: Here's a classic case that just popped up not too many minutes ago actually => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733888/mysql-returning-false-when-multiple-rows-meet-where-clause

Comment: I know the problem has to do with this : $row['content']['Date']; because when I do $row ['Date'], it echos the dates, and when I do  $row['content'] It echos the content but it can't do both when I do $row['content']['Date']

Comment: It's a uni-dimensional array, not a multidimensional array as you are addressing it.

Comment: That's the feeling I got as well.

Comment: ' 
It's a uni-dimensional array, not a multidimensional array as you are addressing it. – Zarazthuztra 26 mins ago'

Comment: I realized I have to put something in between $row['content']['Posted_By']; so in between the two brackets. What do I put in between the two brackets? I can do $row['content'] but not both? Thanks

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what an associative array/hashmap is